# How to get the last row in with method relationships in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to build a chat application with laravel and I have two tables one for the **Conversations** and another one for the **Messages**, and I want to have each conversation with the **last message**. This is the query that I tried:

```
$allConvs = Conversation::with(['messages' => function ($query) {
  $query->latest()->first();
}])    
->get();
```

But it returns the last message for the the first conversation only and null for the others. Is there any other way to do it?
This is my relationships

**Conversation.php**

```
public function messages(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'conversation_id','id')->latest();}
```

**Message.php**

```
    public function conversation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Conversation' ,'id', 'conversation_id');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `HasOne` relationship:

```php
public function latestMessage() {
    return $this->hasOne(Message::class)->latest();
}

$allConvs = Conversation::with('latestMessage')->get();
```

This will still fetch all messages in the background, but only show the latest one for each conversation.

Comment: Works like a charm! Didn't event know there's this method.